# Is sanitization required for user input on alert messages?

Tags: javascript, alert, sanitization

I have a webpage that accepts multiple file inputs. If the file size is too big or file type is not correct, I would like to display an alert to warn the user with something like:

```
FileName: Size exceeds 500kB.
```

Where `FileName` is the file name given by the user. I consider this a user input. Is there a need to do any sanitization here? And what would it be like?

Comment: How do you know what type it is? The extension is not reliable.

Comment: @RobG, I test for it first. If the property can't be read, I will skip the check.

Comment: mime-type detection > file extension parsing, but it is best when they are combined.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow—are you using the [*accept* attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file))? Of course it's just a hint that maybe the file is of a certain type, but it might be useful.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the heads up. I am already using it for mime type. Just discovered that I can also specify the extension :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb I would always sanitize any user input. I know it may sound bad but basically, don't trust your users! That being said, I don't think there is an easy way to hack file inputs but obviously someone could upload a malicious file which normally comes in the form of an .exe or .zip both of which I would eliminate from being uploaded.

If I were you, I would check out [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/), it offers client-side validation and is pretty simple to set up. You can specify what file types to accept and an upload size for file input.

As it stands you can **echo** back the filename without any worrying about sanitizing the filename.

Comment: If you're that paranoid (which you should be anyway), validating client-side is never the answer for security, only an answer for UX. This is the perfect example of security through obscurity. Always validate server-side, regardless. (If this is a completely client-side application, or server-side Javascript, partly ignore my rant.)

Comment: Oh no I completely agree, I only assumed he was doing something on the back end as well being it was a javascript question. Sorry, should have clarified that a little better!

Comment: @Dan, I don't think that answered my question. I am already doing validation server side. I just need to know whether it is safe to echo out file names on alert message.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the upload is not server-side unless it's actually being performed. The form, the alert, etc. are all client-side. So why would sanitation be needed?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Yes.

Comment: @remyabel, to guard against XSS, sanitisation would still be required for javascript input, even if it is displayed client side.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Oh well if that's the case then yes I believe you can echo that without any worries. Sorry I guess I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow That would be a problem if you were taking the filename as a text input, but shouldn't you be using an upload form instead?

Comment: @remyabel, yes, I am using an upload form. The js portion is just a precheck for users to see if there is any error prior to sending the files over.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for the update. I will come back to accept your answer if there is no further contradictory views on this. Give me some time. Thanks.